# Growth of $\pi (2^ n)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is the growth of the function $\pi(2^n)$ polynomial?Is it exponential? The parameter here is $n$. $\pi()$ is prime counting function.

Comment: what has been tried ?

Comment: If you just want a final answer, use the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: What can you say about $2^n/\log(2^n)$ ?

Comment: This is sequence $A007053$ at $OEIS$. Have a look at the second plot (if still required after Yves Daoust's comments)

Comment: Here's a direct link: http://oeis.org/A007053 Almost anything about number theory, the OEIS is sure to have something directly on point or at least relevant.